# python decorator for class methods

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator to register some class methods. How can I get both `self` and `run` parameters correctly?

```py
class Task(object):
    _tasks = []

    @staticmethod
    def register(name):
        def decorator(fn):
            @wraps(fn)
            def wrapper(self=None, run=True, *args, **kwargs):
                if not run:
                    task = defaultdict()
                    task['name'] = name
                    task['fn'] = getattr(self, fn.__name__, None)
                    task['obj'] = self
                    task['args'] = deepcopy(args)
                    task['kwargs'] = deepcopy(kwargs)
                    Task._tasks.append(task)
                else:
                    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return decorator

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @Task.register('foo')
    def foo(self, v1, v2):
        print 'running foo in object {} with arguments {} {}'.format(self.name, v1, v2)

    @Task.register('hello')
    def hello(self):
        print 'running hello in object {} '.format(self.name)

    def load(self):
        self.foo('1', '2', run=False)
        self.hello(run=False)

t1=Test('t1')
t1.load()
```

The following error was raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    TypeError: wrapper() got multiple values for keyword argument 'run'
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have the error you described. (assuming `from functools import *`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the decorator. Your code is actually doing the same as this:

```
def foo(run=False, *args, **kwargs):
    print(run, args, kwargs)

foo(1, 2, run=True)  # TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'run'
```

From your function's signature, python will try to set `run=1`, `args = (2,)` and then run into the `TypeError`.

A fix - though not a very nice one - could be:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    run = kwargs.pop('run', False)  # run defaults to False; remove from kwargs
    print(run, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: What I am doing is that I want to pass a "run" argument to the decorator which will tell the decorator to register the task or just execute it. But I don't want to add this "run"  argument in my class methods as it's doing nothing in the methods. In this case, how should I pass/handle the "run" paramter?

Comment: you could just use what i called `foo` as your `wrapper` function. change its signature and get `run` from `kwargs`. that is actually what [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48617008/4954037) already suggests in detail...

Comment: Yes, this can be a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The run parameter is from the fun, so try to get it from function's parameter:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from copy import deepcopy
from functools import wraps

class Task(object):
    _tasks = []

    @staticmethod
    def register(name):
        def decorator(fn):
            @wraps(fn)
            def wrapper(self=None, *args, **kwargs):
                run = kwargs.pop('run', True)
                if not run:
                    task = defaultdict()
                    task['name'] = name
                    task['fn'] = getattr(self, fn.__name__, None)
                    task['obj'] = self
                    task['args'] = deepcopy(args)
                    task['kwargs'] = deepcopy(kwargs)
                    Task._tasks.append(task)
                else:
                    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)

            return wrapper

        return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3 seems has better hanlder for the parameters, but don't know how to do this in python2:

```
from functools import wraps
def optional_debug(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, debug=False, **kwargs):
        if debug:
            print('Calling', func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@optional_debug
def spam(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

spam(1,2,3)         # 1,2,3

spam(1,2,3, debug=True)    # Calling spam    # 1 2 3
```